# SAPUI5: Keydown on view/page

Tags: sapui5, keycode

in my sapui5 application i have the following code in my Home controller

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
var s = this;

document.addEventListener("keypress", function onPress(event) {
     if ( event.keyCode === 50) {
        alert("Test");
  }
});
```

So when I press the key, the message will be displayed in the home view and in other views, because of the element 'document'

But I want in each view/controller a other Function or Message to the same keycode.

So how can I attach to specific view? I don't want to attach it to a control.

Comment: perhaps you can get the element of the view itself, instead of using the document: `this.getView(). getDomRef().addEventListener...`? This is untested... Do check if the handler is already attached, don't want to add it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove and add the eventlistener every time you visit a view.

View1:

```
onInit: function(){
    this.getRouter().getRoute("myView1").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this); //Call _onRouteMatched on every visit from myView1
},

_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
    document.removeEventListener("keypress"); //Remove the event listener
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function onPress(event) { //Add the event listener again with another message
        if ( event.keyCode === 50) {
            alert("Test View 1");
    }
}
```

View2:

```
onInit: function(){
    this.getRouter().getRoute("myView2").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this); 
},

_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
    document.removeEventListener("keypress");
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function onPress(event) {
        if ( event.keyCode === 50) {
            alert("Test View 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it didn't work correctly. I did following:                                     view 1:  onInit: function() {
   this.getRouter().getRoute("Home").attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
  },

  onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
   var s = this;

   function onkeyPress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 49) { //Verpacken
    document.removeEventListener("keypress", onkeyPress);
     s.navToChooseProject(1);
   
    }
   }
   document.removeEventListener("keypress", onkeyPress);
   document.addEventListener("keypress", onkeyPress);

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it didn't work correctly. I want to navigate from view 1 to view 2 and back by pressing the key == 49.  the first time when i navigate from view 1 to view 2 and to view 3 everything works fine. But backwards from view 3 to view 2 and to view 1 it doesn't work . it seems the eventListener will not removed.